# Socket.IO Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, heroku, socket.io

I am having this issue with socket.io.
In my repository I have the same content installed, and it has been working fine for days. For an unknown reason, I can't get it to work again. I have reinstalled and recreated all content, even start step-by-step all the process, but not possible to get it working.

Any help is appreciated - it really drives me to depression.

```
use strict';
const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const INDEX = '/public/index.html';

const server = express()
  .use((req, res) => res.sendFile(INDEX, { root: __dirname }))
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`));

const io = socketIO(server);
io.emit('ServerToClient', 100);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Client connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', () => console.log('Client disconnected'));
});
```

Client:

```
let socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
socket.on('ServerToClient', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I load the socket in HTML like:
`<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

Comment: I'm currently having the same. Have you managed to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in `use strict';`. You should change it to `'use strict';`

You should not be able to run the server.

I use this link to view a simple example:
[Get started | Socket.IO](https://socket.io/get-started/chat)